# Why are c# constants substituted

Tags: c#, clr, constants

We know quite a few things about constants:

- value must be known at compile time
- value can never be changed at runtime
- they are pushed inside the declaring assembly metadata
- all occurences are substituted by its value in IL
- they may create serious cross assembly versioning problem
- they do not consume dynamic memory since their values are substituted in IL code
- constants can only be primitive types + any reference type initialized to null (MSDN lacks mentioning this part)

Besides the fundamental characteristics of constants, why on earth the clr team decided to substitute every occurence of constant values with literals? In my opinion the jitter would be perfectly capable of loading the containing assembly into memory, searching for the type in metadata and extracting the correct and up-to-date value.

I really don't belive that performance is an issue here, there's not so much constants in any code that would worth it. Not to mention the classic versioning problem of assemblies containing constants.

CLR via C# should have given me an excessive answer, but it just did not.

Comment: Because they are constants, its more efficient to emit code that will ultimately be turned into `mov ax, 1234h` natively is ultimately faster and more efficient than doing a lookup all the time. Immediate addressing is faster than indirect addressing

Comment: _"they may create serious cross assembly versioning problem"_ - only if you don't recompile everything.  Generally people should be using a build server anyway in this day and age of due-diligent TDD; and CI servers and not deploying from your DEV box which is the only way I can think of where you would run into such an issue.

Comment: "natively is ultimately faster and more efficient than doing a lookup all the time"

Bytecode is not supposed to look up the value all the time. In my opinion it would be possible to substitute constant values when jitting to byte code rather when compiling to IL. Performance would not be an issue since every refferring assembly needs to access the defining assembly one time, when jitted. And here is the point where I elegantly contradict myself :) This way almost each and every occurence must be looked up and substituted to bytecode since jitting usually happens at method level.

Comment: So yes, there might be a performance issue here, but I still don't think that is relevant because usage of constant values are far not as common as let's say using plain old value types, when one of the major the intension of inventing value types was performance.

Answer (score 0):

Constants have a problem and you named it: "all occurences are substituted by its value in IL".

Imagine you have a solution with two projects, a Console Application (Project A) and a Core DLL (Project B) that you use for DAL/Infrastructure, e.g.

In your Project B you define a TaxRate constant as a int with a value of 10 and you refer your constant in Project A.

You build (and all constants occurrences will be replaced by the value of "10", in the IL.) and you deploy your application.

Later, the TaxRate changes to 15 and you compile only the project B and replace only the DLL in your existing App - that will work, right?

Yes and no. It will work because you'll have no errors - the only thing that changed was the int value. But in your console application, when you're expecting to get the 15 value, you'll get the value of 10. Why? Because the constant value was replaced in all your projects when you first build your application and you've only replaced the Project B DLL and not the project A.

In this case, if you change to a public readonly int you will not have this problem.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I'm not sure if the scenario described by you and hinted by the OP where you make a change in one assembly but fail to re-compile and re-deploy all assemblies is arguably not realistic nor responsible.  I'm not sure if I agree with the `public readonly int` strategy either as it arguably removes a symptom and doesn't fix the cause. i.e. failure to rebuild everything on a CI server.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer does not explain the real cause why substituting happens at all.

Comment: On the other hand I quite agree on failing to recompile one assembly is not very realistic provided that assembly versioning is properly taken care of.